# Getting maillog filling with bounce and non-delivery notifications that I don't understand or know how to prevent

Tags: centos, postfix

Basic preview of my setup.  I have a farm of centos 7.4 servers on private net all running postfix.  They are all setup to send their mail via a postfix server setup as a mail relay (called proxy1).

Recently I changed the nodes and the relay to add the capability of changing all from addresses to noreply@ourdomain.com so that the messages were friendlier than the equally unreachable [root or other user]@server.ourdomain.com... which works, all messages go out looking like they come from noreply@

But now, and I think this problem only started since then, I get a ton of the following messages in my maillog:

```
Feb 23 16:06:15 proxy1 postfix/cleanup[24600]: 763D06006713: message-id=<20180223210615.763D06006713@proxy1.sw.dev.ourdomain.net>
Feb 23 16:06:15 proxy1 postfix/bounce[24606]: 665566044455: sender non-delivery notification: 763D06006713
Feb 23 16:06:15 proxy1 postfix/qmgr[24499]: 665566044455: removed
Feb 23 16:06:15 proxy1 postfix/qmgr[24499]: 763D06006713: from=<noreply@ourdomain.com>, size=15491, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 23 16:06:15 proxy1 postfix/cleanup[24601]: 7A4E6600670C: message-id=<20180223210615.7A4E6600670C@proxy1.sw.dev.ourdomain.net>
Feb 23 16:06:15 proxy1 postfix/bounce[24603]: 6946D605B401: sender non-delivery notification: 7A4E6600670C
Feb 23 16:06:15 proxy1 postfix/qmgr[24499]: 6946D605B401: removed
Feb 23 16:06:15 proxy1 postfix/qmgr[24499]: 7A4E6600670C: from=<noreply@ourdomain.com>, size=25459, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 23 16:06:15 proxy1 postfix/smtp[24592]: 72CF3605B580: to=<noreply@ourdomain.com>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[173.194.204.26]:25, conn_use=456, delay=0.05, delays=0.01/0/0.03/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host aspmx.l.google.com[173.194.204.26] said: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser o51si1742457qtb.481 - gsmtp (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Feb 23 16:06:18 proxy1 postfix/bounce[24609]: 1EA17605B586: sender non-delivery notification: 2EB73605B584
```

These just keep coming and I presume that in addition to filling my logs and clogging my queue, aspmx.l.google.com must be getting pretty upset.

Looking at other posts I saw on advice about adding this to my aliases:

```
noreply: /dev/null
```

Which actually has seemed to work to remove scrolling messages in the log file and filled queue.

But, I don't know if I just buried the symptom and left a root cause out there or is that the actual answer.

My problem is that I don't know why we are getting all these messages in the first place.

Ordinarily no users in linux are sending any e-mails, except some occasional status jobs and logs from root and a couple other accounts.  We also have layered apps on top running things through mail like OpenNMS which can get noisy.  But, we don't actually want any replies.  This is outbound mail relay only.  I am not setup to receive any replies and don't want to be.

So, is this the correct approach or something else?

Comment: It's  hard to tell, because you haven't included enough log lines, but it _seems_ like you're getting bounces back to the noreply address, which doesn't exist. and these are then going nowhere.

Comment: I don't know if I've just figured out my problem and fixed it or what.  But the problem was clearer in my mailq

I noticed when I tested another message while tailf on the log and mailq in another window I saw that the bounce was associated with a mailq entry that said the message was from noreply@ as well as to: noreply@

which should've been impossible I thought

Comment: but then I tried something.  I had that noreply regex thing set up on all the nodes and the proxy relay.  I removed it from the main.cf on the proxy while leaving it on the node.  retested the same message, and it went out with proper noreply@ on the from but made it to my real to: address fine and the log showed normal processing and no queueing

Comment: I think that somehow having that from regex thing on the relay somehow made it change the to address to noreply even though I can't see how or why.  but, it doesnt seem to need to be there as long as the node has it and it works without it on the proxy so I'll take the win